# Is it possible to insert and render xml in a word document?

Tags: c#, openxml

Let's say we have an xml like this:

```
<w:r>
     <w:t>Sample text to be inserted</w:t>
</w:r>
```

I know I can append this under an element using OpenXml classes like this:

```
Run run = new Run();
run.Append(new Text() { Text = "Sample text to be inserted" });
```

Is it possible to insert raw xml into the document? Are OpenXml classes the only way to insert xml into the document?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you asking how to include custom data in the file, like a mail merge list? Or add XML as text? Both are possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For elements derived from [OpenXmlCompositeElement](https://github.com/xrkolovos/Open-XML-SDK-for-NET-Platform-Standard/blob/master/src/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/Framework/OpenXmlCompositeElement.cs#L195), like eg. `Run` and `Paragraph`, you can set the XML directly via the `InnerXml` property.

```
Run run = new Run { InnerXml = "<w:r><w:t>Sample text to be inserted</w:t></w:r>" };
```